# Create a list of multiples of a number

Tags: python

> Problem:
>
> List of Multiples
> Create a Python 3 function that takes two numbers (value, length) as arguments and returns a list of multiples of value until the size of the list reaches length.
>
> Examples
> `list_of_multiples(value=7, length=5)` ➞ `[7, 14, 21, 28, 35]`
>
> `list_of_multiples(value=12, length=10)` ➞ `[12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120]`
>
> `list_of_multiples(value=17, length=6)` ➞ `[17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102]`

```py
def multiples (value,length):
    """
    Value is number to be multiply
    length is maximum number of iteration up to
    which multiple required.
    """
    for i in range(length):
        out=i
    return i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pythonic way:

```
def multiples(value, length):
    return [value * i for i in range(1, length + 1)]


print(multiples(7, 5))
# [7, 14, 21, 28, 35]
print(multiples(12, 10))
# [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120]
print(multiples(17, 6))
# [17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102]
```

Answer (score 8):

Most Pythonic Way

```py
def multiples(value, length):
    return [*range(value, length*value+1, value)]

print(multiples(7, 5))
# [7, 14, 21, 28, 35]
print(multiples(12, 10))
# [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120]
print(multiples(17, 6))
# [17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102]
```

Comment: What is the name of the * operator as used in [*range(....)]

Answer (score 1):

```py
def multiples(value, length):
    list_multiples = []
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        list_multiples.append(value*(i+1))
        i+=1
    return list_multiples
```

Comment: why not use `for` loop instead?

Comment: it would work as well

Comment: yes, it would work, becaues it's literally how `for` loop is designed to be used. `while` loop works too, but this is not the ideal use-case

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for small values of `length` (< 100) is given by [Nite Block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899762/9948255).

However, in case `length` becomes bigger, using numpy is significantly faster than python loops:

```
numpy.arange(1, length+1) * value
```

With a length of 1000, python loops take almost 4 times longer than numpy. See code below:

```
import timeit

testcode_numpy = ''' 
import numpy
def multiples_numpy(value, length):
    return numpy.arange(1, length+1) * value
multiples_numpy(5, 1000)
'''

testcode = ''' 
def multiples(value, length):
    return [*range(value, length*value+1, value)]
multiples(5, 1000)
'''

print(timeit.timeit(testcode_numpy))
print(timeit.timeit(testcode))

# Result:
# without numpy: 9.7 s
# with numpy: 2.4 s
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy / not in-line way would be :

```
def multiples(value, length):
    l = []
    for i in range(1, length+1):
        l.append(value*i)
    return l
```